# reading from /proc/pid/mem without sudoing the whole python script

Tags: python, linux, file, root

I am reading the other process memory from python script by just opening /proc/pid/mem:

```
reader = open(f'/proc/{pid}/mem', 'rb')
```

and then reading from the random places:

```
reader.seek(address, 0)
memory_content = reader.read(length)
```

Everything is fine, but the fact, that to open /proc/pid/mem I have to sudo the whole python script. Of course, for the sake of sanity, I don't want to do that. What are my options?

- If I understand correctly, I can not `sudo chmod /proc/pid/mem` to allow everybody to read from that process memory (please, correct me, if I am wrong)
- I can not `open` some single file with root privileges from the non-root python script (once again, please, correct me if I am wrong)

Maybe I can create some kind of hard link to the /proc/pid/mem, which would look like a file that does not require to have root access to read from?

Or maybe the easiest way would be to create a proxy program, that would be run from the actual python script with root privileges, that would read from /proc/pid/mem and with which I would somehow cross-process interact?

Comment: Permissions are in the inode itself, all the links use the same inode.

Comment: The proxy method you describe at the end is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need the proxy.

- Your hard link method doesn't work as the permissions remain the same.
- Even if you could give everybody read access to proc/mem, what exactly would you gain with that? From security perspective it would be better to make your whole script run as root and hope you've got it right. There is at least a change for that. By opening memory for everybody to read you would allow anybody harvest secrets from memory making it free for all. So definitely not this one.

If you end up doing the proxy, if you want to do it in Python, you of course need sudo to run that but that will work.  I have written such helpers in C and made them suid root - but this is a matter of preference.